# Include Third Party Jars with Business Objects SDK App

Tags: java, jar, business-objects, buildpath, business-objects-sdk

I am making a small app and I need opencsv for it.  The app is deployed to SAP BI 4.1 and I am using the scheduling functionality.

If I did not need opencsv, I could deploy it to BOE and I would not need to package or extract the jars that the program needs.  The reason being that BusinessObjects already has them in the java/lib folder.

However, how can I include the opencsv jar without packaging all the jars with my jar?  Basically, I need to do the same as "configure build path" in Ecplise for my project, but I need to do that through the Business Objects platform, so that I am configuring their build path.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, include the external jar in the Build Path (I assume you're done this already).  Do not include the external jar in your application's jar, but put it somewhere accessible on the BO server (I put min in `C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Programs\common`), then on the program object's properties panel, include the full path to the jar in the Classpath, ex:

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Programs\common\opencsv.jar

**EDIT**

You can put either the full path in Classpath, or set the Working Directory to be the base directory and just put a relative path in Classpath.

In my case, I set the working directory to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Programs
```

and my Classpath would be:

```
common\opencsv.jar
```

Other jars can be semi-colon deilmited; ex.:

```
common\opencsv.jar;common\activation.jar;path\to\something\else\whatever.jar;d:\foo\bar.jar
```

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about on a high level but I'm fuzzy on the details.  How can I change on the objects properties panel?  So I would go Configure Build Path -> Add External Jar -> Navigate to the jar which is in a common folder on my development and deployment machines.  But then I dont know about this objects properties panel, do I right click on something?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the properties panel in CMC.  That's where you'd set the working directory and classpath.

Comment: So you set both the working directory and the classpath?  Woudl it be like Working Directory ---C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Programs\common\                                                                 and ClasssPath --------  C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Programs\common\opencsv.jar